# How to convert char array to hex and replace it in with substring in hex array?

Tags: c, hex

I have searched it and didn't find a specific solution to my below problem.

I have char array(802.11 packets) which is like below which contain hex values in 0x format.

```
char packet[]={
0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00 //frame control and duration
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff //Broadcast
,0x1c,0x7e,0xe5,0x33,0x80,0xf8//source address
,0x1c,0x7e,0xe5,0x33,0x80,0xf8//BSSID
,0x80,0x42 //sequence number and frame number =0
,0x80,0xbd,0xc8,0x8e,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x00 //timestamp
,0x64,0x00 //beacon interval
,0x31,0x04 //capability info
,0x00,0x08,0x41,0x6d,0x69,0x73,0x68,0x42,0x6f,0x79 //SSID(AmishBoy)
,0x01,0x08,0x82,0x84,0x8b,0x96,0x0c,0x12,0x18,0x24 //supported tags..
,0x10,0x47,0x00,0x10 //FCS}
```

Now SSID field has the string value of 'AmishBoy'. I want to replace that value  which is in text array by converting into hex format of 0x,

```
char *SSID="StackOve";
```

So that every time the only substring of the 'packet' array.

Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that those are just numeric values.  You may type them or view them as hex, but they are just numbers.

Comment: What have you tried, and what was the result you got?  There are lots of ways to do it.  You might want to look up [`memmem()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmem.3.html) and [`memmove()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memmove.html) or 
[`memcpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcpy.html), for example.  Note that `memmem()` is neither standard C nor POSIX, but it is available on some non-Linux systems too (BSD, Mac OS X, AIX, …).

Comment: I am trying to send such packets on raw sockets.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Could you tell me if it is possible.